# How to merge two trees(multi-way tree ) in order (using 'anytree') in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm

how to merge two trees in order (using 'anytree')   in python 
merge the same depth node in order(in order means nodes from  left to right in same depth one by one ) to one new node and add edge weight.
[image]

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree,LevelOrderIter,search
Root = Node(name="0", cart=0, cnt=0, goodsid='-1', parent=None)
node1 = Node(name="1", cart=0, cnt=1, goodsid='-1', parent=Root)
node2 = Node(name="2", cart=0, cnt=2, goodsid='-1', parent=Root)
node3 = Node(name="3", cart=0, cnt=3, goodsid='-1', parent=Root)
node4 = Node(name="4", cart=0, cnt=4, goodsid='-1', parent=Root)
node5 = Node(name="5", cart=0, cnt=5, goodsid='-1', parent=node1)
node6 = Node(name="6", cart=0, cnt=6, goodsid='-1', parent=node1)
node7 = Node(name="7", cart=0, cnt=7, goodsid='-1', parent=node4)
print(RenderTree(Root))
Root_1 = Node(name="a", cart=0, cnt=0, goodsid='-1', parent=None)
node_b = Node(name="b", cart=0, cnt=1, goodsid='-1', parent=Root_1)
node_c = Node(name="c", cart=0, cnt=2, goodsid='-1', parent=Root_1)
node_d = Node(name="d", cart=0, cnt=3, goodsid='-1', parent=node_b)
node_e = Node(name="e", cart=0, cnt=4, goodsid='-1', parent=node_c)
node_f = Node(name="f", cart=0, cnt=5, goodsid='-1', parent=node_c)
node_g = Node(name="g", cart=0, cnt=5, goodsid='-1', parent=node_f)
node_h = Node(name="h", cart=0, cnt=7, goodsid='-1', parent=node_g)
print(RenderTree(Root_1))
```

here is the two sample tree how to merge them

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? You are supposed to attempt it in your own and ask here if you get stuck, SO is not here to do the work for you. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: i'm trying to analyze users' page detail view transfer condition ,each tree represent   one user's condition i have to merge into one over-all condition tree to calculate the view-buy conversion rate

Comment: each tree i have already built,i'm stuck the logic how do the merge

Comment: In that case you should provide a [MCV Code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe look here too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Without any code we'd have to guess how you built the trees.

Comment: thx,i have edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solve the question,this is different from Merge Two Binary Trees with node sum

```
def initial_node(name, cart=0, visit_cnt=1, goods_id='-1', depths=0, order_index=1, parent=None, pr=0):
    node = Node(name=name, cart=cart, visit_cnt=visit_cnt, back_cnt=0, goodsid=goods_id, depths=depths, sons_cnt=0,
                order_index=order_index,
                parent=parent, pr=pr)
    current_Node = node
    return current_Node



def list_extend(l1, l2):
    len1 = len(l1)
    len2 = len(l2)
    if len1 == len2:
        pass
    elif len1 > len2:
        l2.extend([None] * (len1 - len2))
    else:
        l1.extend([None] * (len2 - len1))
    return l1, l2


def tree_merge(node1, node2):
    res = None
    if node1 is None:
        res = node2
        res.goodsid = '-1'
        res.name = str(node2.depths) + '-' + str(node2.order_index)
        res.parent=node2.parent
        return res
    if node2 is None:
        res = node1
        res.goodsid = '-1'
        res.name = str(node1.depths) + '-' + str(node1.order_index)
        res.parent=node1.parent
        return res
    res=node1
    res.cart += node2.cart
    res.visit_cnt += node2.visit_cnt
    res.goodsid = '-1'
    children_1 = list(node1.children)
    children_2 = list(node2.children)
    children_1,children_2=list_extend(children_1,children_2)
    tmp_children=[]
    for i,j in zip(children_1,children_2):
        tmp_children.append(tree_merge(i,j))
    res.children=tmp_children
    return  res
```

this is for  multiway tree merge with node value sum